# query editor not visible in azure SQL DB in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have created an SQL database in azure portal. But there is no tools section in the overview of my DB, so as there is no query editor for me to use.

Instead i have connect with option where only visual studio is shown and not the query editor. Kindly give me a solution why no tools section and how can i get Query Editor.

I had enable(ON) the allow access to all services in the Firewall settings also.

Comment: Gaurav is right, the most comprehensive tool to use is SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Now, Azure SQL database supports Data explorer (preview), you could use it  to query.

[image]

Note: It only show limited object. For full capability please open SSDT.

Comment: Azure portal gets updates frequently. This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Query Editor available on Azure Portal. You can find this experience by navigating to your SQL database and clicking the Tools command and then clicking Query Editor (preview), as shown on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/t-sql-query-editor-in-browser-azure-portal/) Blog post.

Comment: "But there is no tools section in the overview of my DB, so as there is no query editor for me to use.". As the question makes clear, the the Tools thing is gone . As the other answer makes clear, Data explorer is its replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar experience when using Firefox Quantum on a Mac - found the query editor no longer available. I tried using the new 'Data Explorer' and found the query editor window was not working (though I was able to open a query written with an external editor):
[Query editor not working in the 'Data Explorer' with Firefox Quantum on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3kLC.png)

I opened Azure Portal with Chrome v.63 on my Mac, and was able to use the query editor in the Data Explorer:
[Query editor working in the 'Data Explorer' with Chrome on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqzw8.png)

About a week or so ago, when the 'Query Editor' was available through Azure Portal, I was able to type entries in the editor using Firefox.

Other options that work with Windows, Mac, and Linux machines that are provided by Microsoft to query Azure SQL databases include Visual Studio Code with the mssql extension and SQL Operations Studio. Both have continued to work throughout this time for me.